# How to remove the selected tab in Android?

Tags: android, tabwidget

What should I do to remove only the selected tab in android?
Is there anything like remove tab or anything that helps me to remove a tab in the TabWidget class or in another class of the Android API?

Comment: What does `tab` mean? What are you trying to do? Why so many question marks?????

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab? Tab Layout? Tab Widget? [The Tab](http://uk.androlib.com/android.application.tommedley-android-tab-jiCnx.aspx)?

Comment: @imgx64 and @fredley, Toufique is new on Stackoverflow, this is his first question. No need to greet him with silly comments. Edit his question or tell gently tell him how to improve the question. If this would be his tenth question this comments would be okay.
@Toufique what the both wanted to tell you is try to put some more effort into the questions you are asking. It is easier to understand your problem and therefore easier to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use `myTabHost.clearAllTabs()` and than add the wanted tabs again

Comment: Actually I have made an imagebutton in a tab.Now if a user clicks this,that selected tabspec has to be deleted....Now what should I do to remove only that specific tabspace keeping other tabs as those were...????

Comment: For example,let there are two tabs. One is "Home tab" and another is for About.In about tab there is a button named "Close". If user clicks it then Tabhost will contain only "Hometab"....I think you've got my point....

Answer (score 0):

You need save your TabSpec in ListArray, than you delete from that ListArray current TabSpec, after that you make mTabHost.clearAllTabs() and than simply adding saved TabSpec's in cycle to your TabHost.